# relating UART driver with character driver

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, uart

I have written a simple character driver.Now I want to write a UART driver for a omap 4460
processor.
In what way I should start ie how should I relate it with the character driver?

I dont know where to start.I have gone through the manual of the processor and know the functionality of the driver.Please provide me some steps

Comment: What's wrong with `drivers/tty/serial/omap-serial.c`?

Comment: @yegorich I  feel its lengthy and complicated.Is there any other way by which I can write from scratch in a simple manner?

Comment: Then you should find out, what serial driver should provide and implement these routines. You can also participate [here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/arm-kernel/msg317250.html).

Comment: You need to go through omap 4460 processor data sheet, schematics to find out to which uart controller you need to talk to since there will many uart controller. Go through the design document, note down the possible routines which needs to be implemented and develop firmware(OS independent code), so that you can test the functionality and then go ahead and start developing driver on top of it.